# Selenium IE special characters

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, special-characters

In my automation project I'm trying to register a user, it needs to work on Chrome, FF and IE.

It works proerly in Chrome and FF but not in IE. When I enter the email address:

```
setValue(emailField,"test@test.com");
```

IE changes "@" for "2" (in my keyboard the "@" and "2" are in the same key). I've being looking for an explanation but I couldn't find the reason why it changes it and in Chrome and FF it works perfectly, any ideas? Thanks!

**setValue()**

```
public static void setValue(WebElement element, String value) {

        String tagName = element.getTagName();

        //check if WebElement is input or textarea
        if(ConstantsFramework.INPUT.equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || ConstantsFramework.TEXTAREA_MIN.equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) ) {
            // write value in field
            element.sendKeys(value);
        } else if (ConstantsFramework.SELECT.equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
            // select element in combobox
            select(element, value);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ConstantsFramework.ADD_CODE_TO_SET_VALUE_FOR + tagName + ConstantsFramework.CLOSE_BRACKET);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `setValue()`?

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

To type "@" in IE I must press the keys Control+Alt+2 (in my Spanish keyboard):

> setValue(emailField, email_value.replace("@", Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,
>   Keys.ALT, "2")));